# write a program that will accept an integer value in the range of 5-95 and as a multiple of 5

Tags: c

Im a complete newbie in programming. 
I've been instructed to write the program above in the title.
I'm here seeking help from everyone to help me understand and code better.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? i cant get it to exit the loop

more detailed information on the program:
You are asked to write a simple C program that will accept an integer value in the range
of 5-95 and as a multiple of 5 representing the number of cents to give to a customer in
their change. The program should calculate how many coins of each denomination and
display this to the user. Valid coin values are 50, 20, 10 and 5. Your solution (program
and algorithm) should be modular in nature.

```
/*This program acts as a coin changer that helps to provide
  change user their changes in the highest amount.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
// Delcaration of functions
int coins(int fifty, int twenty, int ten, int five);
int main()
{
    // Declare and initialize working storage
    int fifty = 0;
    int twenty = 0;
    int ten = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int user_input = 0;
    int counter = 3;
    int coins(int fifty, int twenty, int ten, int five);
    // Prompt user for input, prints, and loops for 3 attempts
    while (counter > 0)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter an amount within the range of 5 to 95\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter the amount you wish to change: \n\n");
        scanf("%d", &user_input);

        if ((user_input < 5) || (user_input > 95))
        {
            printf("\nInvalid input\n");
            printf("\nNumber of attemps: %d\n\n\n\n", counter);
        }
        counter--;
    }
    printf("\nYou have exceeded the number of attempts\n");
    // Compute number of coins to be given
    fifty = user_input / 50;
    twenty = user_input / 20;
    ten = user_input / 10;
    five = user_input / 5;
    if (fifty >= 1)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of fifty cent coins are: %d\n", fifty);
    }
    else if (twenty >= 1)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of twenty cent coins are: %d\n", twenty);
    }
    else if (ten >= 1)
    {
        printf("\number of ten cent coins are: %d\n", ten);
    }
    else if (five >= 1)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of five cent coins are: %d\n", five);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all indent your program properly so it is readable. Unreadable programs are hard to understand and hard to debug, even more for beginners.

Comment: use `break` if you enter the right number.

Comment: As Kiran said, if the use enters a value between 5-95 then you need to call break; in order to exit the while loop.  Otherwise it will keep repeating the loop 3 times.  If you have not learned how break works you can simply set counter=0 if the input is valid.

Comment: You could change the condition in the `while` to `while ((user_input < 5) || (user_input > 95)) {....`

Comment: I strongly recommend that you not even try to process badly formatted input. If the input is valid, process it.  If it in invalid, just abort with an error message.  If the user wants to make multiple attempts, they can run the program multiple times. Attempting to deal with bad input is difficult, and doing it is not particularly helpful for your education.

Comment: Wow. Thank you all for such helpful advice! I apologise for the badly written and indented code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program that does what you ask.  This program could still be improved vastly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Delcaration of functions
int coinReturn(int coinSize, int value)
{
    int tmp = 0;

    while(value >= coinSize)
    {
        value-=coinSize;
        tmp++;
    }

    printf("Number of %i cent coins are: %d\n", coinSize,tmp);
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    // Declare and initialize working storage
    int user_input = 0;
    int remainingValue;
    // Prompt user for input, prints, and loops for 3 attempts
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter an amount within the range of 5 to 95\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter a multiple of 5\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter the amount you wish to change: \n");
        scanf("%d", &user_input);

        if ( (user_input < 5 || user_input > 95) || (user_input % 5 != 0))
        {
            printf("\nInvalid input!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    //Calculate and Print Output
    remainingValue = coinReturn(50,user_input);
    remainingValue = coinReturn(20,remainingValue);
    remainingValue = coinReturn(10,remainingValue);
    remainingValue = coinReturn(5,remainingValue);
    return 0;
}
```

I would focus on a couple things if I were you and make sure I learned the concept.  These are: 
 - Break Statements
 - Function Declarations and function Definitions
 - Modulo 
 - Flowcharting

This problem can be slightly tricky and flowcharting it when you start is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, my foundation in programming isn't strong yet, im also finding alternative ways to get more exercises to further improve my programming skills as My instructor teaches pretty fast too. hence, im having difficulty understanding or rather visualizing how my codes should look like...

Comment: If this solves your question feel free to mark it and close the question.  Otherwise let us know if something is needed.